# How to type an emoji using robotgo

Tags: go

I want to insert a line with an emoji into the messenger, but I can't, because TypeStr does not insert emojis, I tried several options, not one did not work. I use robotgo. I saw that there is a UnicodeType, but I don't understand how to work with it.

```
package main

import "github.com/go-vgo/robotgo"

func main() {
    robotgo.Sleep(2)
    robotgo.TypeStr("", 0, 1)
}
```

Comment: I'd raise an issue with the developer. It claims to support UTF-8 & the examples show kanji string examples, which do work. But emoji UTF-8 characters do not appear in the terminal correctly.